# Jekyll copying md files instead of processing them

Tags: jekyll

I have a directory full of markdown (.md) files I want to render into a website so I can see what it will look like. I installed Jekyll which I've used a number of times, `cd`'d into the directory and executed `Jekyll serve`.

Jekyll created the `_site` directory and instead of processing my `.md` files into `.html` files, it just copied them into the `_site` directory.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why it's not processing the markdown. Anyone know why?

Comment: does the `.md` files have Front Matter dashes?

Comment: No. Turns out thats what missing. But in this case, it's a directory full of documentation I don't want to add front matter to.

Answer (score 3):

Jekyll only *processes* files with Front Matter.. otherwise, those files are designated as "static files" and simply copied verbatim to the `destination` directory.

Comment: you saved my day, dear friend, I had a typo in my frontmatter which was causing them to be treated as asset files. Thanks a ton

Comment: Glad I could be of help, my friend. :)